# Mercurial .hgrc file

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp

By default on Windows XP Mercurial stores the .hgrc file in (well, in my case) `c:\Documents and Settings\srooks\`. How can I change that location, and have it look for .hgrc file in, for example, `c:\Configuration_Files` ?

Can it be done at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up the [HGRCPATH](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HGRCPATH) environment variable with the path to the configuration file.

Comment: I saw that parameter somwhere but it didn't work. I added in my Control Panel/System/Env. Vars./HGRCPATH var. to the specified directory c:\Conf...Files but when I try to commit he doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: @Rook: You need to set `HGRCPATH` to the filename.  If you set it to the directory name, it looks for files with a `.rc` extension in that directory and reads them all.  If your file is called Mercurial.ini, it won't find it.

Comment: @Niall C. - Ah, I see. Yes, it works now. Thank you both. +A AndiDog

Answer (score 1):

You can move file to c:\Configuration_Files and create link to it in "Documents And Settings" folder. See mklink command.