# Is there a way to check the hg version in ~/.hgrc file?

Tags: mercurial

Can I check the version of mercurial before setting a particular setting in my ~/.hgrc file?  For example, I'd like to enable an extension (say the shelve extension), but only if the hg version is a particular version (say 2.8 or later).  This is particularly useful when one's home directory is shared (think nfs) over many machines that have various versions of hg installed.

Answer (score 5):

That's an interesting one.  There are no conditionals in the `hgrc` format, but there are variable expansions in include lines, so you could put this in your `.bash_profile`:

```
HG_VERSION=$(python -c 'from mercurial.__version__ import version; print version')
```

and then in your `~/.hgrc` have something like:

```
%include ~/.hgrc-$HG_VERSION
```

which would include a file like, `~/.hgrc-2.6.2`

To avoid errors you need a possibly empty file for each version you run, and you could use bash-fu to trim off the minor version for a little flexibility.  It still won't get you greater-than functionality, though.

The more normal way to do this is to use the include mechanism to include host or OS specific hgrc files like:

```
%include ~/.hgrc-$HOST
```

which lets you add in bits that are run only on certain hosts.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have hg read a different hgrc file by checking the version of hg in .bashrc and setting the HGRCPATH Variable accordingly; See [Mercurial .hgrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859762/mercurial-hgrc-file)